# How do I download Ubuntu for another computer, that has no Internet access?

Tags: installation, cd, redirect

Will the entire Ubuntu software fit onto a single CD?

If  I download Ubuntu to a CD, for use on another computer, will it automatically install/partially install on the computer I use for the download?

If alternative measures must be taken to prevent installation on the "host computer", what steps must be taken, since I **do** have **access**, but **do not** have **permission** to download to the "host computer"?

Answer (score 2):

The installation disk, with the default selection of programs, will fit on a CD - largely because it's designed to do so. The desktop version is bootable and can be run independantly.

Ubuntu booted off a LiveCD does not do anything to the host system hard disk unless you ask it to by selecting the "Install" option.

You may want to make a LiveUSB instead - this will perform much better than a CD, and also provide the option of storing data persistently across sessions.

For more serious use, I install Ubuntu "properly" to an external hard drive, and direct the host computer to boot from that. This works well over both USB and eSATA interfaces. Some slight care must be taken when installing updates in this mode - I have known the bootloader, when it's updated, to be written over the bootloader on the host system.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it will fit on a single CD. Download the ISO file and burn to a CD
2. No, a file is saved on the computer you use for the download. Nothing else, so there's no risk whatsoever that 'it' will do something to this computer.
3. No, no measures must be taken to prevent installing Ubuntu on the 'host' computer. Just insert the CD in the CD-drive, reboot the pc, make sure the BIOS is set to boot from CD before the HD. Then Ubuntu will run directly from the CD without affecting the 'host computer' in any way. You can try Ubuntu, see if it fits your needs, etc... If after that, you shut down your computer and remove the cd, next time it will boot from the HD and use what you have installed there. It will be as if nothing has happened.
   Do NOT use the option to 'install Ubuntu on your system' because that will install it on your computer, side-by-side with the original OS. But you will be warned before you do...

Hope this makes things a bit clearer...

Comment: Will the entire Ubuntu software fit onto a single CD? - No it won't - there are over 40000 packages shown in synaptic.

Comment: I overlooked that, but I can't imagine that is what the OP was asking for. Is ANYONE interested in 'the entire Ubuntu software'? From his question, it is clear to me that the OP is interested in the basic OS, so he can try it out... Don't be picky, please

Comment: Thank you to Adrian, daviesgeek, Tinellus, and Elfy. You have all been so very helpful. Good observation, Tinellus. My use of "layman's terms" was a dead giveaway. I don't know how Elfy missed it ; ) , but, you are right, I am, indeed, interested in the basic version.  Still the same, Elfy makes a good "Technical point", for those who are more "Tech-savvy" (in case any of them have this question! haha) I'm just Glad I have all of you working TOGETHER to help me out!

Comment: Elfy remembers trying to find out from someone once what they'd installed that could have caused the issue - the reply was everything ... it might appear that it's a finicky thing to say, but sometimes everything does actually mean everything :)

Answer (score 1):

Lets approach this part by part.

> Will the entire Ubuntu software fit onto a single CD?

This depends upon how you define "the entire Ubuntu software".  Generally speaking, the software archive is [over half a terabyte in size as of April 2013](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mirrors#Mirror_Guidelines).  While there are tools to mirror portions of the archive, it is currently considered impractical to have it available in whole on a single disc.

As to the installation image for Ubuntu, it does not currently fit on a single CD.  The last release that can be located [for example via the mirror in Portland](http://mirrors.cat.pdx.edu/ubuntu-releases/releases/HEADER.html) shows the 12.04.3 release brushing dangerously close to the capacity limit for a CD.  Generally a DVD or USB key will be needed for installation use currently.

> If I download Ubuntu to a CD, for use on another computer, will it automatically install/partially install on the computer I use for the download?

No.  Downloading the disc image does not trigger installation on the downloading computer.

> If alternative measures must be taken to prevent installation on the 'host computer', what steps must be taken, since I do have access, but do not have permission to download to the 'host computer'?

As you've noted elsewhere in a comment that you do not have permission to save content to the computer, you may be best served by any of the following options: [purchasing an installation disc from Canonical](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17), [locating a local Ubuntu social community that may be able to connect you with an installation disc](http://loco.ubuntu.com/teams/), or consult third-party vendors such as [on-disk.com](http://on-disk.com) and [OSDisc.com](https://www.osdisc.com/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is [download Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) and burn a CD of the image you download. You can find more info on burning a CD on Ubuntu [here.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-cd-on-ubuntu). In response to your other question, no the image you download has nothing to do with the computer you downloaded it to. The image is a standalone installer for Ubuntu. In regards to your third question, I don't really understand it :-) Could you rephrase it?

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. Allow me to be more specific. I am currently using a computer that does not belong to me. While I do have access to download, I don't have authourization to download. Example: If I allowed someone to use my computer, as a favor, I would not expect them to download anything to it without permission, so I give the same respect to the person who lends one to me. If possible, I'd like to download directly to the external CD drive, without directly installing anything to the hard drive of the "host computer" in the process.  Can Ubuntu be installed this way? Thank you

Comment: @Shelly No. You have to download the image. However, just downloading and burning the image will do *nothing* to the host computer to change or alter the current state of the computer.